# What is the best practice for reverting changes in case of multiple resource requests?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I've got a method that makes multiple calls on some services that interact with filesystem and database. And the problem is I don't actually know how to properly implement error handling in case something goes wrong halfway. Well, as far as I'm concerned Spring would revert all database changes with `@Transactional` annotation. But what about file system?
Everything that currently comes to my mind is something like this:

```java
public void myMethod() throws MyMethodException{
    try {
        doFirstThingWithDatabase();
        doSecondThingWithDatabase();
        doFirstThingWithFileSystem();
        doSecondThingWithFileSystem();
    } catch(FirstDatabaseThingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    } catch(SecondThingWithDatabaseException(e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        revertFirstDatabaseChange();
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    } catch(FirstFSThingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        revertFirstDatabaseChange();
        revertSecondDatabaseChange(); //and what if first reversion is impossible and also throws an exception?
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    } catch(SecondFSThingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage);
        revertFirstDatabaseChange();
        revertSecondDatabaseChange();
        revertFirstFSChange();
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    }

}
```

But it seems ugly to me since I repeat some code. What is the best practice for such a case?

Comment: Can't you just use a single catch block for all the exceptions and then try to revert each one if there is an exception for any?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring events and event listeners.

In the DB services, before executing the statements that may throw DB exceptions, 
publish an event that will allow a [`TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html) to perform a specific rollback processing if a transaction rollback appears.
That may look like :

```
@Transactional
public void doFirstThingWithDatabase(Foo foo) {
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new FooInsertionEvent(foo));
    fooRepo.save(foo);
}

@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_ROLLBACK)
public void rollBackFooInsertion(FooInsertionEvent fooInsertionEvent) { 
    String info = fooInsertionEvent.getAnyRequiredInfo();
    // use that info to make the DB in the correct state
}
```

In that way, the custom logic rollback related to that DB exception will be performed without any catch.  Apply the same idea for the second DB exception case.

Finally your code could look like :

```
public void myMethod() throws MyMethodException{
    try {
        doFirstThingWithDatabase(); // processed by the listener
        doSecondThingWithDatabase();  // processed by the listener
        doFirstThingWithFileSystem();  // processed below when doSecondThingWithFileSystem() fails
        doSecondThingWithFileSystem(); // no required
    } catch(SecondFSThingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage);
        revertFirstFSChange();
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage);
        throw new MyMethodException(e);
    }

}
```